# Is this tf tree wrong?

Tags: ros-kinetic, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my tf tree about hector slam on raspberry pi

now, There are no errors in terminal.

But also there is no map..

I think it could be a communication problem between nodes.

My Internet is unstable.

If not I can't make any guesses.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290415/is-this-tf-tree-wrong?/) by [DongHyeong Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/34513/donghyeong-kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering the title question, your `tf` tree looks okay to me; it is similar to what we use in most of our mobile bases.

Regarding the absence of a map:

- Have you tried moving the robot around? I'm not sure how hector works, but it may not be getting "enough" info from a stationary sensor to warrant publishing a map;
- Have you taken a look at `rosnode info` for hector? Are you subscribing to the correct map topic in `rviz`?

Your internet connection should not have much of an influence you ROS as long as:

- Everything is running on a single machine;
- The master is routing through `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Best of luck!

---

Originally posted by [Gonçalo S. Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/34829/gon%C3%A7alo-s.-martins/) with karma: 18 on 2018-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0